# Composer no encuentra la extensión de PHP llamada gd

Tags: php, xampp, composer, phpspreadsheet

Estoy tratando de instalar una librería para la creación de reportes de *Excel* desde *PHP*.

Lo siguiente es la salida de la consola del *CMD*:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Cerberos > composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one
  at C:\xampp\htdocs? [Y,n]? y
Using version ^1.10 for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer respositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set packages.

Problem 1
  - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10.1 requires ext-gd *
    -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

  - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10.0 requires ext-gd *
    -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

  - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.10
    -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.10.0, 1.10.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp\php.ini

  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files
    are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

C:\xampp\htdocs\Cerberos >
```

Comment: Por favor no coloques el mensaje de error como imagen pues es ilegible, copia y pega como texto. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, evita algunas clases de comentarios con gente que solo trata de ayudarte a conseguir una respuesta

Comment: no queda claro el entorno en el que te encuentras. Podria ser que solo tuvieras php pero no te interesara instalar ninguna dependencia porque estes usando un docker con dichas dependencias. En ese caso, podrias instalar dicha libreria con `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer solo son dependencias que necesitas instalar. Verifica si tienes dichas dependencias instaladas y en sus versiones correctas.

revisa en tu archivo php.ini si tienes las dependencias que menciona tu error, si no las tienes habrá que buscarlas e instalarlas.

Te dejo el link de la libreria
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Si agregas como hacer lo que mencionas creo mejoraría tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Hay que instalar las librerías de las que depende el proyecto. En este caso:

```
sudo apt install php*-gd
```

Si no se reemplaza el **[*]** por el número de la versión de PHP que tienes instalada, te instalará todas las versiones de la librería que existan.